# How to set the height of panel screen header in Feathers UI?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework, feathers-ui

I created a PanelScreen from feathers.controls. However, I feel like I can only change the width of its header, How can I change the height of its header?

for example:

```
var layout:PanelScreen=new PanelScreen;
layout.title = 'mm';
this.addChild(layout);
layout.validate();
layout.width = 100; // it works
layout.height = 100; // it doesn't work
```

Comment: Wrong forum, maybe? https://forum.starling-framework.org/

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the panel's headerFactory like this

```js
panel.headerFactory = function():Header
{
    var header:Header = new Header();
    header.height = 100;
    return header;
};
```